# How to solve a symbolic equation with symbols in powers

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve

$\dfrac{\rho\  ((1-b)\ \lambda _f\ \lambda _s\ P _A)^{\rho }}{b-1}+\dfrac{\rho  \left(\dfrac{b\ \text{ps}\ x}{1-\text{ps}}\right)^{\rho
   }}{b}=0$

in terms of $b$,

I entered

```
   Solve[((((b ps x)/(1 - ps))^ρ ρ)/
     b + ((-(-1 + b) PA λf λs)^ρ ρ)/(-1 + b)) == 0, b] // Simplify
```

but `Solve` function results to this message

> `!Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>{1]`

How can I solve this equation?

Comment: Please post the actual Mathematica code you have used. You can use the "edit" link below your question to update it.

Comment: >Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)! 3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign. Please consider changing your user name to something more rememberable.

Comment: If you simplify by hand a bit your equation (removing irrelevant bits relative to b): eqn = (b ((ps x)/(1 - ps))^\[Rho] + (1 - 
       b) (P\[CapitalAlpha] \[Lambda]f \[Lambda]s)^\[Rho]) == 0;
 Solve[eqn, b] works;

Comment: Thank you all very much, I am new to this kind of site, I registered today because I am having problems with mathematica, your advices were really helpful. I will try again

Comment: @Chris, you could give that as an answer...

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries: uhm... I don't recognize the equation I simplified! I must have been sloppy or the equation changed? I now agree with Mathematica ;-)

Comment: @Jones I can find solutions of the current equation for $\rho$=0,2,3,4,5 and none for $\rho$=1 if it helps (as mathematica knows how to solve roots of polynomial of order 1-5)

Answer (score 2):

Your equation needs such a massive amounts of assumptions that I can imagine Mathematica can't find the solution. Here is my rough manual derivation in Mathematica's `TraditionalForm` side-stepping many of the intricacies that will prevent Mathematica from solving this (for instance, I assumed $\rho\neq0$). A numerical test in Mathematica follows the derivation.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Table[((((b ps x)/(1 - ps))^\[Rho] \[Rho])/
        b + ((-(-1 + b) PA \[Lambda]f \[Lambda]s)^\[Rho] \[Rho])/(-1 + b)) 
  /. b -> 1/(1 + ((\[Lambda]f*\[Lambda]s*PA (1 - ps))/(ps*x))^(\[Rho]/(1 - \[Rho]))) 
  /. {ps -> Random[],x -> Random[], \[Rho] -> Random[], 
      \[Lambda]f -> Random[], \[Lambda]s -> Random[], PA -> Random[]}, 
  {100}
] // Chop // Quiet
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Indeterminate, 0, Indeterminate, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Indeterminate, 0,
>   0, -6.9383157*10^-9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>    1.196618005*10^-8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>    1.205482381*10^-9, Indeterminate, 0, Indeterminate, 0, 0, 0, 0, Indeterminate, 0, Indeterminate, 0, 0, 0, Indeterminate, 0, 0, 0}

The `Indeterminates` stem from division by (near) zero, where the `Random` function generates a pole.

Comment: You also assumed $\rho\neq1$ obviously.

Comment: @chris Yeah, I wrote "for instance, I assumed $\rho\neq0$" as an obvious example of what to exclude. There are more if you like: `\[Rho] > 0 && b > 0 && \[Rho] != 1 && b != 0 && b != 1 && b > 0 && 
 ps != 1 && x != 1 && ps != 0 && ps > 0 && x > 0 && 
 PA > 0 && \[Lambda]f > 0 && \[Lambda]s > 0`. I used these in `Assuming`, but that didn't help much.

Comment: Quite a few indeed :-)